# highcharter animation in flexdashboard

Tags: r, highcharts, flexdashboard, r-highcharter

I've run into an issue when trying to control/edit the animations of highcharts in flexdashboard. It appears that the animation preferences I pass through using plotOptions are ignored.

I have a [normal .Rmd](https://rstudio.theloomaproject.com/content/803/Untitled.html) that shows the intended animation options and a [flexdashboard](https://rstudio.theloomaproject.com/content/804/ReprexFlex.html) with the same graph code.

My goal is to just show those highcharts in the flexdashboard with their animation settings, so I'm open to alternatives as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/jbkunst/flexdashboard-highcharter-examples/blob/gh-pages/booms/index.Rmd) example (which is the code for [this](http://jkunst.com/flexdashboard-highcharter-examples/booms/index.html) dashboard)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Nico for posting, but I believe you might be running an older version of highcharter 0.7.0 as the hc_add_series_times_values is deprecated. 
(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highcharter/versions/0.7.0/topics/hc_add_series_times_values) Also, for the delay in my examples I'm using the exact same code that you are using and getting the same results as seen in the reprexs.

Answer (score 0):

I had an outdated version of .Rmarkdown.